# how can create other conection zf2 apigility?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

How can create a connection to my data/database.db
I get this connection only with one config but don't from another config in the same file `module.php`

**In this code it's ok**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
                'factories' => array(

                            'Music\V1\Rest\Album\AlbumMapper' =>  function ($sm) {
                            $adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                            return new \Music\V1\Rest\Album\AlbumMapper($adapter);
                            },
                ),
        );
    }
```

But if I try with two connection doesn't work:

```
   public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
                'factories' => array(

                            'Music\V1\Rest\Album\AlbumMapper' =>  function ($sm) {
                            $adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                            return new \Music\V1\Rest\Album\AlbumMapper($adapter);
                            },


                            'Music\V1\Rest\Albumjson\AlbumjsonMapper' =>  function ($sm) {
                            $adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                            return new \Music\V1\Rest\Albumjson\AlbumjsonMapper($adapter);
                          },

                ),
        );
    }
```

I get the [next error with zf2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3xV9.jpg):

> An abstract factory could not create an instance of musicv1restalbumjsoncontroller(alias: `Music\\V1\\Rest\\Albumjson\\Controller`).

Comment: might be similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719501/cant-get-logger-service-in-zf2

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with your database setup. It means your controller class cannot be found. Did you properly register a controller called `Music\\V1\\Rest\\Albumjson\\Controller`?